# Unable to initialize main class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit when trying to run pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, conda

I have a `conda` installation of `python 3.7`

```
$python3 --version
Python 3.7.6
```

`pyspark` was installed via `pip3 install` (`conda` does not have a native package for it).

```
$conda list | grep pyspark
pyspark                   2.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Here is what `pip3` tells me:

```
$pip3 install pyspark
Requirement already satisfied: pyspark in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.7 in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyspark) (0.10.7)
```

`jdk 11` is installed:

```
    $java -version
    openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

When attempting to `import pyspark` things are not going so well. Here is a mini test program:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os, sys
def setupSpark():
    os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "pyspark-shell"
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").master("local").getOrCreate()
    return spark

sp = setupSpark()
df = sp.createDataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
df.show()
```

That results in :

> Error: Unable to initialize main class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter

Here is full details:

```
$python3 sparktest.py 
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparktest.py", line 9, in <module>
    sp = setupSpark()
  File "sparktest.py", line 6, in setupSpark
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").master("local").getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 367, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Any pointers or info on working environment in conda would be appreciated.

**Update**  It may be the case that `pyspark` were available from conda-forge only: I only started to use that for `conda install` recently. But it does not change the result:

```
conda install -c conda-forge conda-forge::pyspark

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


# All requested packages already installed.
```

Re-running the code above still gives us:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743

Comment: I think Spark 2.4 doesn't support Java 11

Comment: @mck You're correct. I am presently running on spark 3 (came back to this question yesteerday).  I will update the question

Comment: "*conda does not have a native package for it*" this isn't true now, nor when question was asked (e.g., [from conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyspark/files)). I suggest retrying using `conda install`. Also, never use `pip3` or `pip2` in a Conda environment. Conda does not provide `pip2` or `pip3` aliases for the `pip` binary, and thus they often resolve to a user- or system-level installation.

Comment: @merv  pip *is* part of a normal conda env: conda explicitly says to use them for libraries that are not included in their own builds. That includes many libraries.

Comment: For  `pyspark` it may be the case that using `conda-forge` were necessary: that is an approach I only just recently started to follow.  I updated the question

Comment: [It was also on the **defaults** (**anaconda**) channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyspark/files). I wasn't saying not to use `pip`, I am saying never to use it with a **2** or **3** at the end. Conda does not create such an alias when it installs `pip`.

Comment: @merv I had checked many times: the pip3 was resolving to the correct version within the `miniconda3/bin` dir ,  Is that not the case on your system?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Seems I'm wrong: [someone added the `pip3` entry point to the Conda Forge feedstock this past year](https://github.com/conda-forge/pip-feedstock/issues/51) and AnacondaRecipes has merged it. Thus, only users with `pip >= 20.2` have `pip3`, which, to answer your question, is not the case for many of my envs. From the code, it looks like a corresponding `pip2` is not added. I will still continue to recommend preference for simply `pip` since it is consistent across all versions.

Comment: ah understandable - it was in any case a nice thing to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not really an answer but instead a workaround.A real answer is still appreciated!

I was unable to get `pyspark` to run at all within a `conda` environment. Instead I backtracked to using `brew` installed python and spark/pyspark in 3.9. Here are the commands I used.

```
brew install python3
git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask" fetch --unshallow
brew install apache-spark
brew link apache-spark
brew link --overwrite apache-spark
brew install scala
```

Answer (score 1):

The following steps are for running your mini test program in Conda environment:

Step 1: Create and activate a new Conda environment

```
conda create -n test python=3.7 -y
conda activate test
```

Step 2: Install the latest `pyspark` and `pandas`

```
pip install -U pyspark pandas   # Note: I also tested pyspark version 2.4.7
```

Step 3: Run the mini test. (I have updated some changes to create DataFrame from `DataFrame` instead of `dict`)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os, sys
import pandas as pd

def setupSpark():
    os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "pyspark-shell"
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myapp").master("local").getOrCreate()
    return spark

sp = setupSpark()
df = sp.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}))
df.show()
```

Step 4: Enjoy the output

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  4|
|  2|  5|
|  3|  6|
+---+---+
```

Java version that I used to install `pyspark`

```
$ java -version
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: This is no different than what I had tried  (no new info afaict). Glad it worked for you. Any ideas why the disparity in results?

Comment: I guess the problem may be because the versions of `pyspark` and `java` that you are using are incompatible. Tried to upgrade `java` version and repeat my steps to see if it works for you.

Comment: From the original question:  `pip3 install pyspark` so it's the same version. as you have    (you're using the same command).  `java 11.0.2` is absolutely compatible with the current version of pyspark .

Comment: Also pls read my answer below:  the pyspark and java are *the same* as installed under conda but _working under brew_ .  So the versions question you raise seems to already be answered.

Comment: In your question, you were using `OpenJDK` while I used `Oracle JDK` so that is the only difference that I can think of. You should try to install `Oracle JDK` (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html) and repeat the above steps.

Comment: Hmm the same jdk that fails for me works on brew installed pyspark.  A separate question: i thought that oracle stopped producing their own jdk's several versions ago. I'll look at that link to see what's up with that.

Comment: From the official pyspark docs _Spark runs on Java 8/11_ https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/.   So you're actually on an unsupported configuration

Comment: Interesting! I think they have already tested Java 8/11 so for the later versions than this, we use it at our own risk.

Comment: I upvoted since this shows useful thought and might help someone.